# How to remove unchecked item from textbox?

Tags: javascript, text, checkbox, textbox

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getVal(chk, adto)
{
  var ad="";
  if (chk.checked) 
  {
    ad=document.getElementById(adto).value + chk.value;
    document.getElementById(adto).value = ad;
  }
  else  
  {
  }
}
</script>
```

The first block is working as I wanted but when user unchecked the check box it should remove the value from the text box.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="0" id="chk0" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 0<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="1" id="chk1" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="2" id="chk2" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="3" id="chk3" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="4" id="chk4" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="5" id="chk5" onclick="getVal(this, 'inp0')">value 5<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="inp" id="inp0" readonly><br>
```

Please help how to remove the unchecked options from the text box.

Comment: It is easier to find all checked checkboxes and concatenate their values into the string, that to remove a single string. (and the same code works for adding and removing values!)

Comment: Is the user also allowed to enter their own text into the textbox, or are the contents of the textbox completely controlled by the checkboxes?

Comment: The text box is readonly textbox is completely controled by the checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/e4TBN/)

Assuming all checkboxes with the same name adds to the same field.
If not we will need more code.

I also assumed the boxes are wrapped in a form tag

```
function getVal(chk, adto) {
  var ad=[];
  var checks = chk.form[chk.name];
  for (i=0;i<checks.length;i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked) {
      ad.push(checks[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById(adto).value = (ad.length>0)?ad.join(" "):"";

}
```

Comment: your code is working in fiddle but it is not working my code , the above was just example what i want do i am doing the project init i am using checkboxes about 40 are there i wanted to do same everything is same name ids etc just they are in php code with and like echo's and all that are needed in php and id="5" is written in id='5'

Comment: if i want to post that value seat nos with the help of php how to do it i tried it but it is sending that value to next page with the help of $_POST['inp0']